# Using a 0 rather than skipping the group entirely if nothing is found

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How can I use a 0 as a "placeholder" here?

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:G578, "select G, sum(C) where D='Income' group by G label sum(C) 'Total Income'")
```

So that

| Month | Total Income |
| --- | --- |
| August 2021 | $784.59 |
| October 2021 | $200.00 |
| November 2021 | $312.74 |

becomes

| Month | Total Income |
| --- | --- |
| August 2021 | $784.59 |
| September 2021 | $0.00 |
| October 2021 | $200.00 |
| November 2021 | $312.74 |

The quickest hacky fix would be just to have an entry of 0$ for September in the data somewhere, but I am wondering if there is a more ""professional"" way to do it

Comment: Month Column: use `ArrayFormula(DATE(2021,SEQUENCE(4,1,8),1))` to output consecutive months. Total Income Column: use `ArrayFormula(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY(...),FALSE),0))` to output the respective amount.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet